# Trying to set CSS for active/default tab in menu/navbar but the active class is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component where I'm generating tabs based on the amount of child elements in my Tabs component.

I have CSS set up for the base style of the tabs as well as the `:focus` styles but when the component loads I'm trying to apply the same styles from `:focus` to an `:active` class so that the default tab when the menu is loaded appears as the active tab, but for whatever reason just passing styles into an `:active` class isn't working with my styled components.

Right now when the menu loads the tabs appear as inactive with the standard styling.

My tab component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Tabs = (props: Props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);
  const childrenList = React.Children.toArray(children);

  const tabs = childrenList.map((child, idx) => {
    const title = (child as any).props.title ?? idx;
    return (
      <StyledTabs key={title} onClick={() => setTab(idx)}>
        {title}
      </StyledTabs>
    );
  });

  const current = childrenList[tab];

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{tabs}</div>
      <div>{current}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabs;

const StyledTabs = styled.button`
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  :focus {
    color: #1471da;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1471da;
    outline: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

/* These Styles don't work */
    :active {
    color: #1471da;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1471da;
    outline: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the web-standard ":active" pseudo selector with a custom-set "active" CSS class. The pseudo  generally just active *while* an element is being clicked. See e.g. here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_active2.

On the other hand, e.g. at https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/, the "active" class is used to say that tabs are currently open. To customize the tab that is currently open, you need to make sure it is set to have a custom class, such as "active". Then, you can style it in CSS with ".active" rather than ":active".